# getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE) is undefined in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I have application with an activity and a service, I need to save some value in the activity and retrieve in the service.

i could save the value using  SharedPreferences in the activity, however,  when I try to retrieve the value in the BroadcastReceiver, it says  **getPreferences is undefined for service.**

**how could I retrieve my value in BroadcastReceiver?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDITED** to reflect change of the original question from `Service` to `BroadcastReceiver`.

Instead of using `getPreferences(int mode)` in the `Activity` use...

```
getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode).
```

The `getPreferences(int mode)` method is a convenience method for the above and simply passes the `Activity` class name as the `name` parameter. This implies it should really only be used for a given `Activity` to store its own internal preferences and not preferences that need to be global to other app components.

In the case of a `BroadcastReceiver` the `onReceive(...)` method is passed a `Context` parameter so you can use `context.getSharePreferences(<some_name>, <mode>)` to get the `SharedPreferences` saved by the `Activity`.

Comment: You could also have your service receive a Context object when it is bound to your Activity. That way you always have a reference to your application Context. If you have Context, you have SharedPreferences.

Comment: @RyanGray : But as you say, that depends on the `Activity` being bound to the `Service`. In the case of the `Service` being started by some other app component, this won't be the case. Obviously it comes down to the design/functionality of the app and what the individual components do. The `getPreferences(int mode)` method is simply a convenience method which calls `getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)` passing the `Activity` class name as the `name` parameter and implies it should only be used by an `Activity` for its own internal preferences rather than those global to the app.

Comment: sorry, i just mad an edit, it's BroadcastReceiver, not service

Comment: Where is your broadcast receiver? A private class within an activity? or a stand-alone class?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AndroidWalkthroughApp4 extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {        
        // get EditText object
        EditText editText = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        // get preferences object
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        // set text to our saved value
        editText.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getInt("chars", 0)));

        // don't forget to do this, or your app will crash!
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // get EditText object
        EditText editText = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        // get preferences object
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        // create editor from preferences object
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        // save and write length of EditText 
        editor.putInt("chars", editText.getText().length());
        editor.commit();

        // don't forget this either!
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```